# Why can't we use const members in static member functions?

Tags: c++, constants, static-methods

```
class TConst
{
    const int i;
    int& ref;
    public:
    TConst(int n):i(n),ref(n){}
    static void p1(){prn(i);}//error here
};
```

My compiler generates an error when I try to use a `const` class member in a `static` member-function.

Why is it not allowed?

Comment: Please always post the full error that you get.

Comment: const int is still bound to an object, not to class.

Comment: In a static method there is no class instance so there are no class members ... FYI you can make this `static const int i = 42;` if you want to use it this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `const` member is initialized during the object construction.  The `static` members are not dependent on the object creation and don't have access to `this` pointer hence they don't know where your `const` member variable resides.

Answer (score 14):

`const` means different things. In this case, it means that `i` is immutable after it's been initialized. It *doesn't* mean it's a literal constant (like I believe you think it means). **`i` can be different for different instances of `TConst`**, so it's logical that `static` methods cannot use it.

Comment: It's always so simple ) Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It wouldn't work even if it wasn't `const`:

```
error: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
```

Static functions can not access non-static member variables. This is because non-static member variables must belong to a class object, and static member functions have no class object to work with.